# Spaces between value inputs on CSV file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, export-to-csv

I am currently coding for a arithmetic quiz and want to write the results to a CSV file, I am currently using this code to do so:

```
with open('Class1.csv','a') as Class:
        Class=csv.writer(Class)
        Class.writerow([username,score])
```

however when more than one data entry is put into the CSV file there is a space in between the entries how do I remove this?

[image: Double spaced entries]

Comment: class.seek(username, io.SEEK_CUR); #This give you a backspace.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Python 2.7, then you need to write the file as binary. This is done as follows:

```
with open('Class1.csv','ab') as Class:
    Class = csv.writer(Class)
    Class.writerow([username,score])
```

This can be seen in the [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) documentation.

If you are using Python 3.x, then the following is needed:

```
with open("Class1.csv", "a", newline="")
    Class = csv.writer(Class)
    Class.writerow([username,score])
```

Comment: To add to Martin's answer. He preserves your `Class` identifier, and it is technically fine. However, you should avoid that confusing identifier for the file objects. Using `f` in such simple case may be just fine -- meaning **a file object**. Also, do not reuse that identifier immediately for another purpose. You should write `writer = csv.writer(f)` and then `writer.writerow(xxx)`.